# How to find the perimeter of the triangle inscribed within the square.

Tags: geometry, triangles

In square $ABCD$, the length of its sides is $5$. $E, F$ are two points on $AB$ and $AD$ in
such a way so that $∠ECF = 45^\circ$, find the maximum value of the perimeter of
$ΔAEF$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like drawing the square and finding the points required?

Comment: Please show your try first.

Comment: I tried drawing it. But I cannot solve it. You have to find the area of AEF. @MohammadZuhairKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since they asked for the maximum, we know that AE must be equal to AF to maximise the perimeter.  Then the figure would be symmetrical about the diagonal, so $∠ECB=∠DCF=\frac{90^o-45^o}{2}=22.5^o$.  Now $tan(22.5^o)=\frac{EB}{BC}=\frac{EB}{5}$.

We have $EB=2.07106...$, giving us $AE=AF=5-EB=2.92893...$.  By Pythagoras' theorem, $EF=\sqrt{AE^2+AF^2}=4.1421...$.

Summing it all, $AE+AF+EF=10$.  Strangely, this is a rather nice number.  Currently working on a solution that does not require calculator.

Here is another approach which requires zero use of the calculator.  Making use of the same approach as above, $AE=AF=5-5tan(22.5^o)$, and $EF=(5-5tan(22.5^o))\sqrt{2}$.  Our total sum is $10-10tan(22.5^o)+(5-5tan(22.5^o))\sqrt{2}$.  Our goal now would be to find the mysterious $tan(22.5^o)$.

We make use of the trigonometric identity $tan(2A)=\frac{2tan(A)}{1-tan^2(A)}$.  Noting that $tan(45^o)=1$, we let $2A=45^o$.  We have, now, $1=\frac{2tan(A)}{1-tan^2(A)}$.  Solving this quadratic equation by letting $tan(A)=x$, we get $tan(22.5^o)=-1\pm\sqrt{2}$.  Knowing that $tan(22.5^o)$ is positive, it is $-1+\sqrt{2}$.

Substituting $tan(22.5^o)=-1+\sqrt{2}$ into $10-10tan(22.5^o)+(5-5tan(22.5^o))\sqrt{2}$, we get 10.

Comment: Is there anyway other than trigonometry?

Comment: I don't think so...  However, it actually just uses tangent, which is rather simple.  I hope you understand.

Comment: @JamesCoren what do you think?  Does it help?

Comment: "since they asked for the maximum, we know that AE must be equal to AF to maximise the perimeter" I don't see this. Yes, that is the most symmetric position, but how do you _know_ that moving $E$ and $F$ a _tiny_ bit clockwise doesn't increase circumference?

Comment: @XcoderX That's an entirely different scenario. You are right that in many cases the symmetric answer is the most efficient, but it needs to be proven in _every single case_. You can't just assume that it's true this time for the sole reason that it usually is.

Comment: Yes, @Arthur, i realised it was different.  I think it is exactly because of this that the symmetry must hold.  I considered the worst case scenario, where E was on A and F was on D, leading me to believe that the symmetrical solution would work.

Comment: Note that choosing $E=B$, $F=A$ gives you a degenerate triangle with the same perimeter.

Comment: So, you've tested the two extreme cases and found that of the two the symmetrical one has larger perimeter. This does not say _anything_ about any of the triangles in-between. It's a good heuristic (and in problems on this level it's usually the true answer), but it is _not_ a valid proof. What if $\angle BAE = 21^\circ$ instead of $22.5^\circ$? What if it's $10^\circ$? You can test as many of these you want, and I will _always_ be able to find more for you that you haven't tested. You will be able to convince me that it's _probably_ true, but it is still not a proof.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter thanks for the info!!  I think every single possible triangle has the same area.  I tried on another triangle...

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do is to draw $CBG$ triangle which is equivalent to $CDF$. It is easy to see the rest:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Big surprise: The perimeter $p$ of such a triangle is $=10$, whatever the choice of $E$.

*Proof.* Let the side length of the square be $1$, and put $|AE|=:x$, $|AF|=:y$.  If $\angle(ECB)=:\alpha$, $\angle(FCD)=\beta$ then
$$1=\tan(\alpha+\beta)={\tan\alpha+\tan\beta\over1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}={2-x-y\over1-(1-x)(1-y)}\ .$$
It follows that $xy=2(x+y-2)$, which leads to
$$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=(x+y)^2-4(x+y)+4=(x+y-2)^2\ .$$
Since $x+y\leq2$ we therefore   obtain
$$p=x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=x+y+(2-x-y)=2\ .\qquad\square$$